# Resque jobs can't connect to outside hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications, resque, rails-activejob

In my Rails app, I've got ActiveJob setup to work with Resque. I've created the this job to send iOS push notifications with the `grocer` gem:

```
class SendPushNotificationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(device_token, msg)
    # TODO: Move the grocer initialization somewhere else.
    pusher = Grocer.pusher(
      certificate: ENV['PUSH_CERT_PATH'],
      passphrase:  ENV['PUSH_CERT_KEY'],
      gateway:     "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
      port:        2195,
      retries:     3
    )

    Resque.logger.debug "PUSHER OBJECT IS #{pusher.inspect}!"

    notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
    device_token: device_token,
    alert: msg)

    Resque.logger.debug "NOTIFICATION OBJECT IS #{notification.inspect}"

    res = pusher.push(notification)

    Resque.logger.debug "PUSH RESULT IS #{res.inspect}"
  end
end
```

The output of the Resque log when this job is picked up is:

```
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24074: Found job on default
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24074: got: (Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SendPushNotificationJob", "job_id"=>"c88619a4-d2ea-4b27-a3c8-3ea5be04a130", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["<my_device_token>", "Test message"], "locale"=>"en"}])
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24074: resque-1.26.0: Processing default since 1467860911 [ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper]
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24074: Running before_fork hooks with [(Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SendPushNotificationJob", "job_id"=>"c88619a4-d2ea-4b27-a3c8-3ea5be04a130", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["<my_device_token>", "Test message"], "locale"=>"en"}])]
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24074: resque-1.26.0: Forked 24092 at 1467860911
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24092: Running after_fork hooks with [(Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SendPushNotificationJob", "job_id"=>"c88619a4-d2ea-4b27-a3c8-3ea5be04a130", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["<my_device_token>", "Test message"], "locale"=>"en"}])]
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24092: PUSHER OBJECT IS #<Grocer::Pusher:0x007f862152f4f0 @connection=#<Grocer::Connection:0x007f862152f630 @certificate="<cert path>", @passphrase="<passphrase>", @gateway="gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", @port=2195, @retries=3>>!
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24092: NOTIFICATION OBJECT IS #<Grocer::Notification:0x007f8627a23f00 @identifier=0, @device_token="<my_device_token>", @alert="Test message", @encoded_payload=nil>
```

Then the exception happens:

```
** [22:08:31 2016-07-06] 24092: (Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"SendPushNotificationJob", "job_id"=>"c88619a4-d2ea-4b27-a3c8-3ea5be04a130", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["<my_device_token>", "Test message"], "locale"=>"en"}]) failed: #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Here's what I know:

1. The gateway URL is being set properly.
2. The environment variables are correctly set.
3. This job works when using `perform_now` instead of `perform_later`.

**Lastly, this is not an issue with `grocer`**. I created another job that simply logs the source of a URL:

```
class TestExternalConnectionJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(url)
    res = HTTParty.get(url)

    if res
      Resque.logger.debug "SUCCESS"
      Resque.logger.debug res.body
    else
      Resque.logger.debug "FAILURE"      
    end
  end
end
```

Running `TestExternalConnectionJob.perform_later('http://stackoverflow.com')` in the Rails console produces this output in the Resque log:

```
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24285: Found job on default
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24285: got: (Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"TestExternalConnectionJob", "job_id"=>"523da5ca-2b6c-452e-95ef-33edece69996", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["http://stackoverflow.com"], "locale"=>"en"}])
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24285: resque-1.26.0: Processing default since 1467861281 [ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper]
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24285: Running before_fork hooks with [(Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"TestExternalConnectionJob", "job_id"=>"523da5ca-2b6c-452e-95ef-33edece69996", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["http://stackoverflow.com"], "locale"=>"en"}])]
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24285: resque-1.26.0: Forked 24300 at 1467861281
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24300: Running after_fork hooks with [(Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"TestExternalConnectionJob", "job_id"=>"523da5ca-2b6c-452e-95ef-33edece69996", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["http://stackoverflow.com"], "locale"=>"en"}])]
** [22:14:41 2016-07-06] 24300: (Job{default} | ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper | [{"job_class"=>"TestExternalConnectionJob", "job_id"=>"523da5ca-2b6c-452e-95ef-33edece69996", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>["http://stackoverflow.com"], "locale"=>"en"}]) failed: #<SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to stackoverflow.com:80 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)>
```

So, *tl;dr*, none of my Resque jobs are able to connect to external services.

**Appendix**

My `lib/resque.rake` file:

```
require 'resque/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup => :environment do
    require 'resque'
  end
end
```

My `config/initializers/resque.rb` file:

```
require 'resque'

Resque.redis = Redis.new(url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
Resque.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}_resque.log"))
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, writing that question was *an enormous waste of time.*

For some reason, after a reboot and restarting all of my processes, I was able to connect to outside hosts.

Previously, I had restarted the processes many times *without* rebooting. I'm using `eye` to manage them, so several times in trying to solve this I issued an `eye restart` command to restart all of the processes my app depends on (`postgres`, `redis` and `resque-worker`). Every time after the restart I would get the same error.

But somehow, a reboot did the trick.

Computers are weird sometimes.